# Parse a string with two delimiters [[, {{

Tags: python, regex, python-re

When parsing this string:

```
import re
s = 'hello how are you? {{foo;;[[1;;2;;3]];;bar;;[[0;;2;;3]]}} im okay {{ABC;;DEF;;[[10;;11]]}}'
for m in re.findall(r'{{(.*?)}}', s):
    print('curly brackets: ', m)
    L = m.split(';;')
    print(L)
```

The `m.split(';;')` should give this:

```
['foo', '[[1;;2;;3]]', 'bar', '[[0;;2;;3]]']
```

instead of:

```
['foo', '[[1', '2', '3]]', 'bar', '[[0', '2', '3]]']
```

**How to modify the split to do this?**

Comment: See https://ideone.com/Mz6NxU

Comment: Regular expressions are not ideal parsers.  You can many arbitrarily complicated things (see https://github.com/Davidebyzero/RegexGolf/blob/master/regex%20for%20matching%20multiplication%20-%20factoring%20method.txt) but the question better suited for code golf than stackoverflow.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Since it's a lit bit different than the duplicate @WiktorStribiżew, could you post it as an answer? It would be great for future reference.

Comment: (@WiktorStribiżew Comments tend to be cleared sometimes)

Comment: It is always the same: `char` + `(?![^OPEN-CLOSE-DEL-CHARS]*DEL-CHAR)`. No need to multiply the same kind of knowledge.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew For such complicated things, multiple examples are often welcome to understand the concept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use this split with a negative lookahead:

```
L = re.split(r';;(?![^[]*])', m)
```

Here it will split on `;;` with a negative lookahead `(?![^[]*])` which means on right hand side there should not be a `]` after 0 or more non-`[` characters, thus ignore matching `;;` inside `[...]`.

Note that this assumes `[` and `]` are balanced and unescaped.